# XML For R Statistics - OSX Version 2.15.1

Tags: r

I have tried to locate the XML package for the above version of R with no success. I have looked on http://www.omegahat.org/ and it goes to a 404 page: http://www.omegahat.org/XML

Basically I am trying to install the RGoogleAnalytics package and that also fails, though i suspect that is because I don't have the XML installed. Does anyone know where I can get the XML package from?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Have you tried a CRAN mirror? softliste.de works for me on OSX and R 2.15.1 - Not `RGoogleAnalytics`, but rather `XML`. I get an error that `RGoogleAnalytics` isn't available for R 2.15.1

Comment: Ah ok I shall try the softlist.de alternative. Thanks for the help. Thanks also for confirming RGA isn't available and I wasn't being dumb!

Comment: Looks like version numbers of `XML` on omegahat and CRAN are slightly different. Also, I could install from omegahat.org; please see edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I came across [this guide](http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=220), which gives some good hints as to installing `RGoogleAnalytics`. Here's a slight modification, in case the `XML` library really can't be found at omegahat:

The last part in step 2 asks you to install the `XML` library from omegahat. I could successfully install the package from CRAN, however. So simply `install.packages("XML")` at the R prompt should work.

Next, the guide says that you need to download the `RGoogleAnalytics` ***source*** package directly from Google at the following [URL](http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/downloads/detail?name=RGoogleAnalytics_1.1.tar.gz).

Once that was downloaded (and after I installed the `RCurl` package), I could install `RGoogleAnalytics` successfully.

For instructions on installing R packages from source, you could see [this article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-packages-from-source-on-mac-os-x/) on r-bloggers.com or [the appropriate section of the R Installation and Admin documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Building-from-source-on-_0028Mac_0029-OS-X)

**EDIT:**

The [Google Code page for RGoogleAnalytics](http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/) does suggest using the `XML` package from omegahat, and it does look like that package is a different version from the one on CRAN. I could successfully install the omegahat version using R 2.15.1 with the following from the R prompt

```
install.packages("XML",repos="http://www.omegahat.org/R",type="source")
```

**EDIT2: installing RGA from source**

If everything is prepared according to the RGA instructions on the [Google page](http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/), you should be ready to install the RGA package *from source* with the following line (I had to add `--no-multiarch`, since `XML` wasn't installed for 32-bit architecture):

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/RGoogleAnalytics_1.1.tar.gz",
  repos=NULL,type="source",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")
```

Comment: Well I managed to load it all by following the Getting Started section on the RGAanalytics site (http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/downloads/detail?name=RGoogleAnalytics_1.1.tar.gz) despite it not working following other installation guides. Thanks for everyones help. I am going for a beer!

Comment: @PeterStannett, the .tar.gz file contains the RGA source code, so you need to install as such. I see that that particular line is cut off in techpad's blog. I'll post it as an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/
```

Although it is equally possible that you should be using the XML package from CRAN. I just updated my older version with the current binary install (for R 2.14.2 on MacOS 10.5.8).